# Laravel 9 syntax error, unexpected token "return"

Tags: php

Alright, so I'm trying to make a special access only page for staff basically a custom maintenance code with a password but I keep running into this error in my middleware:
**syntax error, unexpected token "return"**

Here's my middleware code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class webAPIchecker
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

    $route = $request->route()->getName();

    // Offline

    $adminsOnlyPass = config('web.offlinePass');


    if ((web('offline_enabled') && !in_array(session('admins_only'), $adminsOnlyPass)) || !web('offline_enabled') && session()->has('admins_only'))
        session()->forget('admins_only');

    if (web('offline_enabled') && !session()->has('admins_only') && !Str::startsWith($route, 'offline.')
        return redirect()->route('offline.offline');

    if (!web('maintenance_enabled') && Str::startsWith($route, 'maintenance.'))
        return $this->disabled('Maintenance', $middleware, $isPOST);

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

Comment: Please, format your code. 
Since its not readable at this stage.

Comment: What about now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss closing parenthesis `)` at the end of this line:

```
if (web('offline_enabled') && !session()->has('admins_only') && !Str::startsWith($route, 'offline.')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\web()

Comment: Because there is no such function by default so no idea what you mean by using it